# Magento 2.3 V1/Search with sortOrders not working in REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Magento 2.3 Search Criteria with REST API, SortOrders not working in V1/Search API.

I am trying to fetch Category products using Magento REST API by below request URL.

**http://127.0.0.1/magento230ee/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_ids&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC**

Using Above query I have to get the same result whether a name field is ASC or DESC Order in Query.

Only SortOrder is not working for the above query. How to apply sortOrders filter in product collection using the above query.

Comment: did you try `asc` and `desc` ? I mean in small caps instead of all caps

Comment: I have tried using ASC and DESC

Comment: that's weird, have you tried DESC  or both not working?

Comment: None of working. Its not consideration for sortOrdres

Comment: I also faced this issue and found that magento sorts the result according to relevance value. At the end mobile team handled this at their end ; )

Comment: Are you looking for get Product you may use /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at& searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC& searchCriteria[pageSize]=10& searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

Comment: @Divyarajsinh I am looking for product with Layer navigation attribute facet details for a category.

Comment: As name field is not in result it will give always the same result as it will be not considered. I.e Sort order is only applied if the field is present in the result.

Comment: @Divyarajsinh I have try with ID asc but they also not working id is available in result

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I am also facing the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: I created custom API to update details but I want to update detail based on store code and store code is collected from payload any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below api, I hope its working for you.

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento230ee/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Test&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

Comment: I created custom API to update details but I want to update detail based on store code and store code is collected from payload any idea?